# Conditional Expectation of measurable random variables

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$, then show that for random variables $X,Y$ that $X=Y$ almost surely on the measure $\mathbb P$,  when both $\mathbb E(|Y|^2|H) = X^2$ and $\mathbb E(|Y ||H) = X$ where $H$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal F$.

Using the tower property:

$\mathbb E (\mathbb{E}(|Y ||H)) = \mathbb E(X) \iff \mathbb E(|Y|) = \mathbb E(X)$

$\mathbb E (\mathbb E(|Y|^2|H)) = \mathbb E(X^2) \iff \mathbb{E}(|Y|^2) = \mathbb E(X^2)$

Is this the right line of thinking? I went a little wayward using definitions of variance from here and other things but can't think how to get $X=Y$ a.s.?

Answer (score 1):

The best we can say in this setting is that $X=\lvert Y\rvert$ almost surely (the assumptions are satisfied with $Y=-X$ hence $X=Y$ may not hold).

In order to see this, show that 
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(X-\lvert Y\rvert\right)^2\mid\mathcal H\right]=0
$$
by expanding the square and noticing that $X$ is $\mathcal H$-measurable.

Comment: Can you explain why setting that expectation to 0 works here? I don't fully understand what you did here

Comment: Then you get that $\mathbb E\left[\left(X-\lvert Y\rvert\right)^2 \right]=0$ hennce $X=\lvert Y\rvert$.

Comment: Thanks! I've simplified everything else but get stuck evaluating $\mathbb E^\mathbb P (X^2\mid\mathcal G)$? Is it just $E(X^2)$?

Comment: It is actually $X^2$, since $X$ is $\mathcal H$-measurable.